# Convert a cross-distance matrix from class "Crossdist" to a matrix

Tags: r, class, matrix, distance

I calculated the following cross-distance matrix using the proxy-package and want to use it as a matrix-object. However, crossdistance is of class "crossdist" and using crossdistance <- as.matrix(crossdistance) does not convert it to a matrix, but instead it is still of class "crossdist". Any comments are more than welcome :)

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2),ncol=1)
mat2 <- matrix(c(1,2,2,2,3,3),ncol=1)

(crossdistance <- proxy::dist(mat1,mat2,type="euclidean"))
```

**Output:**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    2    2
[2,]    0    1    1    1    2    2
[3,]    0    1    1    1    2    2
[4,]    1    0    0    0    1    1
[5,]    1    0    0    0    1    1
[6,]    1    0    0    0    1    1


str(crossdistance)
```

**Output:**

```
 'crossdist' num [1:6, 1:6] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 - attr(*, "method")= chr "Euclidean"
 - attr(*, "call")= language proxy::dist(x = mat1, y = mat2, type = "euclidean")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could also use `dim<-`

```
crossdistance2 <- `dim<-`(c(crossdistance), dim(crossdistance))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try

```
crossdistance <- `attr<-`(
  as.matrix(
    as.data.frame.matrix(crossdistance)
  ), "dimnames", NULL
)
```

and you will see

```
> crossdistance
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    2    2
[2,]    0    1    1    1    2    2
[3,]    0    1    1    1    2    2
[4,]    1    0    0    0    1    1
[5,]    1    0    0    0    1    1
[6,]    1    0    0    0    1    1

> str(crossdistance)
 num [1:6, 1:6] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
```

Comment: Thank you!, works perfectly, I will use akrun answer, due to it being shorter and quicker compared with microbenchmark, but yours works as well :)